# Excel: Searching for text within a cell array and returning text from that cell

Tags: excel

[image]

In A7, I would like to return the number at the beginning of the cell in which I find a certain piece of text. So, for example, if I search for the word "question" I would like to return the number 4.

I have tried using this:

=LEFT(CELL("address",INDEX(A1:A5,MATCH("*"&"question"&"*",A1:A5,0))),1)

Because CELL("address",INDEX(A1:A5,MATCH("*"&"question"&"*",A1:A5,0))) returns the cell reference ($A$4), but it takes the cell reference as the text rather than the text in that cell.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ***Microsoft-365*** user can utilize `FILTER()` function.

```
=LEFT(FILTER(A1:A5,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C2,A1:A5))),1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This formula is not perfect because it cannot handle if there is more than one match or if the number to extract is over 9 but could be a starting point:

[image]

Formula in B9:

```
=LEFT(INDEX($A$1:$A$5,MATCH("*"&B8&"*",$A$1:$A$5,0)),1)
```